# Is there a simple sequence with bi-alternating parity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

Any polynomial $p$ over $\mathbf Z$ has either alternating or constant parity, i.e., either
$p(n)$ is even for all $n$, $p(n)$ is odd for all $n$, or $p(n)$ alternates; odd, even, odd, even etc.
This follows just by noting that any polynomial $a_dn^d + \cdots + a_1n+a_0$ equals
$$n(a_dn^{d-1}+\cdots+a_1)+a_0,$$
so for even $n$, the parity of $p(n)$ is fixed (it is the same as that of $a_0$), and for odd $n$, the parity is also fixed (it is the same as that of $a_0+a_1+\cdots+a_d$).

I would like a simple expression which has bi-alternating parity, i.e., some expression $f(n)$ whose parity for successive $n$ looks like:
$$\text{even, even, odd, odd, even, even, odd, odd},\dots$$

What is the "simplest" kind of expression I can create which has this property? It cannot be polynomial by the reasoning above, but maybe something algebraic (involving radicals)? I would like to avoid floors/ceilings and have something nicely differentiable.

Comment: $\dfrac12+\dfrac{\sin((2n+1)\pi/4)}{\sqrt 2}$ goes $1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,\ldots$

Comment: $\big \lfloor \frac n2\big \rfloor$.

Answer (score 2):

Probably one of the simplest such sequences is the sequence of [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), $T_n =  \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. For nonnegative integers it starts as

$$0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, \ldots$$

It is odd when $n = 1, 2 \pmod 4$ and even when $n = 3, 0 \pmod 4$. Note that it can be given as a polynomial expression with coefficients over $\mathbb{Q}$ (but not over $\mathbb{Z}$, as your question shows).